# I'm integrating Linkedin to my app using OAuth 2.0, but a refresh token is not returned

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm integrating Linkedin to my app, but a refresh token is not returned. The access token endpoint (https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken) just returns an access token and a TTL. Is there a way to refresh this token within 60 days, so the users don't have to reauthorize again?

This is a sample response returned:

```
{
    "access_token": "XXXX",
    "expires_in": 5183999,
    "scope": "r_emailaddress,r_liteprofile,w_member_social"
}
```

On authorization, the users authorize these scopes: r_emailaddress, r_liteprofile, w_member_social and the products selected for the app are Sign In with LinkedIn, Share on LinkedIn.

Answer (score 0):

Per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/programmatic-refresh-tokens), you must be an approved Marketing Developer Platform partner.